# How to convert large size hyperspectral from tif to lan

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, remote-sensing, hyperspectral-sensor

I tried to convert hyperspectral from .tif to .lan format. There are three file with size about 1.5GB , 750MB and 200MB respectively.

I use this code

```
from osgeo import gdal

src_fname = 'file.tif'
dst_fname = 'file.lan'
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('LAN')

sds = gdal.Open(src_fname)
dst = driver.CreateCopy(dst_fname, sds)
dst = None  # close dataset; the file can now be used by other processes
```

It's works with hyperspectral file less than 200MB. But when file size more than that, it's failed. I didn't get output file with .lan format. What solution to handled this problem? Do i need other software to do file convert?

Comment: As a comparison try if gdal_translate https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html can handle your file. Usage: `gdal_translate -of LAN input.tif output.lan`. If gdal_translate works then it must be possible to do the same with Python as well by making some changes to the code. I can't tell directly what.